# conda 'source deactivate' produces error: too many arguments

Tags: python, environment, anaconda, conda

I'm trying to test out creating virtual envs through `conda create` on OS X. It's my first real foray into virtual envs so I'm still wrapping my mind around how to tool them. My first test was

```
$ conda create -p /users/me/anaconda/envs/envtest
$ source activate /users/me/anaconda/envs/envtest
```

But when I go to take it down via `source deactivate`, I get:

```
Error: too many arguments.
```

Some [googling](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/339) seems to indicate that there is some configuration in my .profile file that's affecting this but that file is empty. It will probably help to show my `.bash_profile`:

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM function

# Added by Canopy installer on 2013-09-12
# VIRTUAL_ENV_DISABLE_PROMPT can be set to '' to make bashprompt show that Canopy is active, otherwise 1
VIRTUAL_ENV_DISABLE_PROMPT=1 source /Users/ibebian/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/bin/activate

PYTHONPATH="/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/:$PYTHONPATH"
export PYTHONPATH


set PATH = "$PATH:/Users/ibebian/Desktop/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/bin"

# added by Anaconda 1.8.0 installer
export PATH="/Users/ibebian/anaconda/bin:$PATH"
```

Any insight here? Much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the problem is the `set PATH = "$PATH:/Users/ibebian/Desktop/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/bin"` line. `set` sets default arguments for bash functions (`$1`, `$2`, and so on). So `deactivate` thinks it is being called as `deactivate PATH = "$PATH:/Users/ibebian/Desktop/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/bin"`, rather than just `deactivate`.

To assign to a variable, just use

```
PATH="$PATH:/Users/ibebian/Desktop/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/bin"
```

(note there are no spaces here)

Comment: Thanks for that. I ended up killing the enthought package since I wasn't using it, and I removed the `set` and spaced as you suggested. I also `export` the `PATH`s.