# Conda 'source deactivate' error: too many arguments

Tags: bash, conda

In short:

```
bir@N2C:~/conda$ source deactivate root
Error: too many arguments.
bir@N2C:~/conda$ conda-env list
# conda environments:
#
root                  *  /home/bir/conda

bir@N2C:~/conda$ source deactivate root
Error: too many arguments.  # I also tried from ~
```

This doesn't seem to be the problem in [this almost identically titled question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23002694/conda-source-deactivate-produces-error-too-many-arguments) which attributes the problem to use of "set" in the bash configuration:

```
bir@N2C:~$ ls -a | grep bash
.bash_aliases
.bash_history
.bash_logout
.bashrc
```

A minimal script also indicates no default parameter:

```
bir@N2C:~/bin$ cat ./test
#!/bin/bash
echo "$1"
bir@N2C:~/bin$ ./test
                      # $1 set by default would be here wouldn't it?
bir@N2C:~/bin$
```

So I'm stumped...

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? I've check the "set" problem and that's not it.

Answer (score 2):

Search the bash files you showed above for any commands containing set. If you have them, either comment them out or move them to ~/.inputrc instead.

Comment: also make sure you reload these files (simple solution is to logout/login)